# Getting wrong answer from Uva judge for the 3n+1problem

Tags: java

I tried to submit the 3n+1 problem several time but failed to get it accepted on the Uva judge.I wrote the program in java.Can anyone point out the mistake in my program.
Problem statement:-
https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=29&page=show_problem&problem=36

My program:-

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Main
{
    static String ReadLn (int maxLg)  // utility function to read from stdin
    {
       byte lin[] = new byte [maxLg];
       int lg = 0, car = -1;
       String line = "";

        try
        {
        while (lg < maxLg)
        {
            car = System.in.read();
            if ((car < 0) || (car == '\n')) break;
            lin [lg++] += car;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        return (null);
    }

    if ((car < 0) && (lg == 0)) return (null);  // eof
    return (new String (lin, 0, lg));
}

public static void main (String args[])  // entry point from OS
{
   Main myWork = new Main();  // create a dinamic instance
    myWork.Begin();            // the true entry point
}

void Begin()
{
    String input;
    while((input=Main.ReadLn(255))!=null){
    StringTokenizer str=new StringTokenizer(input);
    int n1=Integer.parseInt(str.nextToken());
    int n2=Integer.parseInt(str.nextToken());
    int max=0;
    for(int i=n1;i<=n2;i++)
    {
        int no=calculate(i,0);
        if(max<no){
            max=no;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(n1+" "+n2+" "+max);
    }
}
static int calculate(int a,int sum){
if(a==1)
{
    return sum+1;
}
else if(a%2==0)
{
    sum+=1;
    return calculate(a/2,sum);
}
else
{
    sum+=1;
    return calculate((3*a+1),sum);
}

}
}
```

I am very sorry for bad indentation of my code.

Comment: Can you supply some sample input and output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it accepted by UVa judge. The problem was didn't considered that the second number can be smaller than the first number. You have to consider that case in which the second number is the starting of the series.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the input/output. The code in your question reads one line and then prints one line. The input/ouput on the UVa page specifies to use a "series" for input and use "for each" as ouput. In other words: read all the input lines, calculate, and then write all the output lines.

Here is some code to help you read all the input-lines (the `ReadLn` method in your question looks overly complicated):

```
public static List<int[]> readCycleRanges() throws Exception {

    List<int[]> cycleRanges = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (!(line == null || line.trim().length() == 0)) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
        int i = Integer.valueOf(st.nextToken());
        int j = Integer.valueOf(st.nextToken());
        cycleRanges.add(new int[] { i, j, 0 });
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    return cycleRanges;
}
```